# How to setup TeamCity to work with Cypress without installation of node, xvfb, cypress for each test execution

Tags: docker, docker-compose, teamcity, cypress

I want to run my cypress.io tests in CI (Teamcity) by scheduled timers. Tests will be run very frequently that is why I am interesting to execute them as quick as possible
This is my current implementation.
I run teamcity-server with 3 teamcity-agents with the following docker-compose.yml

```
    version: "3"
    services:
      server:
        image: jetbrains/teamcity-server:2020.1.2
        ports:
          - "8112:8111"
        volumes:
          - ./data_dir:/data/teamcity_server/datadir
          - ./log_dir:/opt/teamcity/logs
      teamcity-agent-1:
        image: jetbrains/teamcity-agent:2020.1.2-linux-sudo
        environment:
          - SERVER_URL=http://server:8111
          - AGENT_NAME=docker-agent-1
          - DOCKER_IN_DOCKER=start
        privileged: true
        container_name: docker_agent_1
      teamcity-agent-2:
        image: jetbrains/teamcity-agent:2020.1.2-linux-sudo
        environment:
          - SERVER_URL=http://server:8111
          - AGENT_NAME=docker-agent-2
          - DOCKER_IN_DOCKER=start
        privileged: true
        container_name: docker_agent_2
      teamcity-agent-3:
        image: jetbrains/teamcity-agent:2020.1.2-linux-sudo
        environment:
          - SERVER_URL=http://server:8111
          - AGENT_NAME=docker-agent-3
          - DOCKER_IN_DOCKER=start
        privileged: true
        container_name: docker_agent_3
```

And in building steps I am using node:10.18.1 in settings as per screen below:

[image]

My buildings steps are following now:

1.

```
npm install yarn --no-save
yarn install --no-lockfile
```

2. 

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e -x
export CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER="%env.cypress_cache_path%"
export CYPRESS_VAR1=%env.var1%
export CYPRESS_VAR2=%env.var2%

apt-get update && apt-get -y install libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnotify-dev libgconf-2-4 libnss3 libxss1 libasound2 libxtst6 xauth xvfb

yarn silent --spec "%env.cypress_path_to_landing_pages%"
```

3. yarn generate:html:report

This is I need to run for every time I execute tests and it takes around 10 mins to execute each test set taking 60-70% time on installation of all dependencies which are

```
  {
    "@types/mocha": "^8.0.0",
    "cypress": "4.11.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "mocha": "^7.2.0",
    "mochawesome": "^6.1.1",
    "mochawesome-merge": "^4.1.0",
    "mochawesome-report-generator": "^5.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.6"
  }
```

- apt-get install xvfb libgtk-3-dev libnotify-dev libgconf-2-4 libnss3 libxss1 libasound2 (which I need to install extra for linux)
  I do belieave that main heavy dependency are cypress and xvfb packages.

I see 3 ways how to avoid this huge execution time:

1. to have a docker image compatible with teamcity containing all cypress ENV: node, cypress, xvfb etc. In that case I do not need to install it every time I run tests. I was following cypress documentation and aware that special docker images are designed for that
   https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-docker-images

cypress/base

cypress/browsers

cypress/included

But they are not compatible with Teamcity server (Teamcity agents need to have a java wrapper) or I dont know how to run them from docker-compose.yml
I tried this but TeamCity server was not able to find this agent and agents tab was empty

```
version: "3"
services:
  server:
    image: jetbrains/teamcity-server:2020.1.2
    ports:
      - "8112:8111"
    volumes:
      - ./data_dir:/data/teamcity_server/datadir
      - ./log_dir:/opt/teamcity/logs
  teamcity-agent-2:
    image: cypress/included:3.4.0
    environment:
      - SERVER_URL=http://server:8111
      - AGENT_NAME=docker-agent-2
      - DOCKER_IN_DOCKER=start
    privileged: true
    container_name: docker_agent_2
```

2. To cache node_modules and xvfb somehow. I see https://cypress.slides.com/cypress-io/cypress-on-ci#/5/2/0 but can not understand how to put it in my building steps
3. Setup building dependencies in TeamCity and install all dependencies once in one build and move artifacts (node_modules, xvfb etc) somehow to next build which will run tests by timers.

How I understood cypress documentation myself they are suggesting to follow point 1 from my list but how to run their images as teamcity agents I did not understand

any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering on my own question. For those who got stuck with the same this is an optimized way to setup Teamcity and Cypress:

my docker-compose.yml from the topic is correct. run it buy

```
docker-compose up -d
```

setup 2 different configurations in Teamcity

1. to install dependencies (will be run very rare when you need to update dependencies)
2. to run tests (will be run often when you need to run a test)

in the first config use simple 1 building step

```
npm install yarn --no-save
yarn install --no-lockfile
```

and container settings as per screen
[image]
after create artifacts by
node_modules => node_modules.zip

in second configuration setup dependency to get node_modules from first configuration as per screen
[image]